# Node Inspector Installation fails on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I was trying to install Node Inspector in Ubuntu using:

```
sudo npm install -g node-inspector
```

The attempted installation ends with :

> ws@0.4.31 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
>   (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

And a prompt.

Node version : 0.11.9, npm version: 1.3.17

Comment: Please share the text in `builderror.log` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try install `ws`**:**

`sudo npm install -g ws`

And try install `node-inspector`**:**

```
su
npm install -g node-inspector
```

Comment: It gave me the same prompt:
    (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
but seemed to install after a second. Seems to be working now, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try this
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local 
npm install node-inspec